# How to prove this Brownian motion convergence?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion. How do I show the following?

$$
\alpha > \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{W_t}{t^{\alpha}} = 0 \text{ a.s.}
$$

Showing convergence of this in probability is easy enough, but I am not sure of how I could get the stronger a.s. result. By (super)martingale convergence I know that the limit is almost surely finite, but how do I show that it is equal to $0$?

Comment: If $X \to Y$ almost surely and $E(X^2) \to 0$, we have $Y=0$ by Fatou's lemma

Comment: Thanks, you are right, that does it. If you wish to post that as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: What is the super martingale under consideration?

Answer (score 2):

Exploiting the martingale property of the Brownian motion, we can show that for each positive $\varepsilon$, the inequality 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\sup_{2^n\leqslant t\leqslant  2^{n+1} }\left|W_t\right| \gt \varepsilon 2^{n\alpha} \right\}\leqslant 4 \varepsilon^{-2} 2^{n(1-2\alpha)},$$
holds. We then conclude by the Borel-Cantelli lemma.

Comment: Are you using Kolmogorov Maximal Inequality?

Comment: @minion I don't know the name, maybe it refers to Doob's maximal inequality.